# Delete feature with GDAL(Vector Layers) in python is not working?

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, vector-layer

I am using gdal module in python to get raster seamline/foot print. For that I have used gdal.Polygonize() funtions.

I wanted to have only one polygon of data area instead of thousans of big and small polygons.

I have tried to delete feature later one if feature are is very small but it could not delete feature.

I am going to share my script here if anyone find the mistake in my procedure...

Here is my scripts:

```
#Author:        Shiuli Pervin
#Date of start: 20160721
#purpose:       reading  raster file from server and produce seamline/footprint.........
# resources:
#               http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#iterate-over-features
#               https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html
import arcpy
import os
from osgeo import gdal, ogr,osr
import sys
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
import numpy as np
import struct

startTime=time.time()
# this allows GDAL to throw Python Exceptions
gdal.UseExceptions()

#  get raster datasource
raster=r"F:\Geodaten\Eigene\Luftbild\Orthobilder\20130802\Klostermoor2013_Ortho-0-0.jpg"
src_ds = gdal.Open( raster, gdal.GA_ReadOnly )
#print src_ds 
if src_ds is None:
    print 'Unable to open %s' % src_filename
    sys.exit(1)
print "Done"

srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

#print srcband

# creating a true / false raster to detect data area
def getNoDataValue(raster):
    raster =gdal.Open(raster)
    band = raster.GetRasterBand(2)
    return band.GetNoDataValue()
bandArray = srcband.ReadAsArray()
#bandArray[bandArray== noDataValue] = 0
bandArray[bandArray>10] = 9

# creating a data mask raster.................................
# get raster georefence info
geotransform = src_ds.GetGeoTransform()
originX = geotransform[0]
originX = geotransform[0]
originY = geotransform[3]
pixelWidth = geotransform[1]
pixelHeight = geotransform[5]
cols = src_ds.RasterXSize
rows = src_ds.RasterYSize###we are here
raster_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
raster_srs.ImportFromWkt(src_ds.GetProjectionRef())

#....................... Create memory target raster
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', src_ds.RasterXSize, src_ds.RasterYSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)

# creating a data mask raster.................................
mask_ds=gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', src_ds.RasterXSize, src_ds.RasterYSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
mask_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)

# Create for target raster the same projection as for the value raster

target_ds.SetProjection(raster_srs.ExportToWkt())

##Get the band to write to
out_band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

#And write our processed data
out_band.WriteArray(bandArray)

#making band Array true/false
bandArray[bandArray>0] = 1
print bandArray

# creating a data mask raster.................................
mask_ds=gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', src_ds.RasterXSize, src_ds.RasterYSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
mask_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)

# Create for mask raster the same projection as for the value raster

mask_ds.SetProjection(raster_srs.ExportToWkt())


##Get the band to write to mask dataset
mask_band = mask_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

#And write our processed data
mask_band.WriteArray(bandArray)



## seve raster.py application
#inputs for function
threshold = 2
connectedness = 4
prog_func = gdal.TermProgress
##creating destination raster--------
dst_filename= r"P:\August2016\raster_polygonize_gdal\st"
drv = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
dst_rs = drv.Create( dst_filename,src_ds.RasterXSize, src_ds.RasterYSize,1,
                srcband.DataType )
wkt = src_ds.GetProjection()
if wkt != '':
    dst_rs.SetProjection( wkt )
dst_rs.SetGeoTransform( src_ds.GetGeoTransform() )     
dstband = dst_rs.GetRasterBand(1)

##result1 = gdal.SieveFilter( out_band, mask_band, dstband,
##                             threshold, connectedness, 
##                             callback = prog_func )

# create output datasource for shp file polygon geometry

dst_layername =r"P:\August2016\raster_polygonize_gdal\POLYGONIZED_STUFF_seamline"
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

if os.path.exists(dst_layername+".shp"):
    drv.DeleteDataSource(dst_layername+".shp")
    print 'deleted'
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( dst_layername + ".shp" )

# project vector geometry to same projection as raster
targetSR = osr.SpatialReference()
targetSR.ImportFromWkt(src_ds.GetProjectionRef())
dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = targetSR )

# adding a field to polygon
newField = ogr.FieldDefn('Raster', ogr.OFTString)
newField.SetWidth(100)
dst_layer.CreateField(newField)
new_field = ogr.FieldDefn("Area", ogr.OFTReal)
new_field.SetWidth(32)
dst_layer.CreateField(new_field)
# Raster polygonize to create polygon feature from raster........
#result=gdal.Polygonize( srcband, None, dst_layer, -1, [], callback=None )
result=gdal.Polygonize( out_band, mask_band, dst_layer, -1, [], callback=None )

# calculating area of new polygons
for feature in dst_layer: #and (feature2 in range(count)):
    geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    area = geom.GetArea()
    # calculating feature area using gdal in python
    feature.SetField("Area", area)
    feature.SetField('Raster', raster)
    dst_layer.SetFeature(feature)
dst_ds.Destroy()
# opening shp file ceates in gdal.polygonize()
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dst_fc=drv.Open(dst_layername+".shp", 0)
)
#itterating over geometry und getfield
dst_layer=dst_fc.GetLayerByIndex(0)
count=dst_layer.GetFeatureCount()

fd=[]#feature to delete
for feature in range(count):
    inFeature = dst_layer.GetFeature(feature)
    area=inFeature.GetField("Area")
    # filtering atribute value to delete unexpected polygons
    if int(area)>=2:
        print feature, area
        fd.append(feature)

for i in fd:
    dst_layer.DeleteFeature(i)

dst_fc.Destroy()
#raster=r"F:\Geodaten\Eigene\Luftbild\Orthobilder\20130802\Klostermoor2013_Ortho-0-0.jpg"


src_ds=None

print "we are done..."
endTime=time.time()
print "this script took "+ str(endTime - startTime) +" Seconds"
```

Comment: I have tried to solve the delete feature in several way but it did not workout. At last I habe coppied the selected feature as I need to a newly created shape file. It has fulfilled my requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have a solution to my question. I would like to share:

*I have tried to solve the delete feature in several way but it did not workout. At last I habe coppied the selected feature as I need to a newly created shape file. It has fulfilled my requirements*

I would like to share the specific part of my script:

```
    # create a new shp file to copy the big polygon
outfile=r"P:\August2016\raster_polygonize_gdal\seamline_poly"
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")# driver to create shp file

# first deleting the file if already exist
if os.path.exists(outfile+".shp"):
    drv.DeleteDataSource(outfile +".shp")

outfc=drv.CreateDataSource(outfile + ".shp")
layer = outfc.CreateLayer(outfile, srs = targetSR)

#itterating over geometry und getfield
fc_layer=dst_ds.GetLayerByIndex(0)
count=fc_layer.GetFeatureCount()

# Add input Layer Fields to the output Layer
inLayerDefn = fc_layer.GetLayerDefn()

for i in range(0, inLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
    fieldDefn = inLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i)
    layer.CreateField(fieldDefn)

# outlayer defination
outLayerDefn = layer.GetLayerDefn()

for feature in range(count):
    inFeature = fc_layer.GetFeature(feature)
    area=inFeature.GetField("Area")

    # filtering atribute value to delete unexpected polygons

    if area>=2.0:
        print feature, area
        outFeature = ogr.Feature(outLayerDefn)
        # Add field values from input Layer
        for i in range(0, outLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
            outFeature.SetField(outLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetNameRef(), inFeature.GetField(i))

        # Set geometry as centroid
        geom = inFeature.GetGeometryRef()
        #centroid = geom.Centroid()
        outFeature.SetGeometry(geom)

        # Add new feature to output Layer
        layer.CreateFeature(outFeature)


outfc.Destroy()
```